# Upload a file with expired access token get 400 error

Tags: box-api

I am using `BOX Java SDK` v2 which has an auto refresh token functionality.

According to the code, during sending a request with a expired access token, the `SDK` workflow are the following:

1. send request with expired access token.
2. get 401 (invalid_token)
3. send refresh oauth request with valid refresh token and get new access token and refresh token.
4. send the original request with new token again.

The issue is after get new token, the sdk send original upload request with new token, but it get `400 (Bad Request)` error. If I call sdk upload a file with a valid token, it return 201.

I also call the download a file with expired token, then sdk auto refresh token, re-execute download request which return without any error. So it means this execute request - refresh - re-execute works fine.

Is this a bug in `SDK` or I missed something? please help.

Comment: I believe it may have been broken for an evening.  Are you still seeing this problem?

Comment: I fixed this by myself with some tricky code.

Comment: Since the SDKs that involve uploading use inputstream to load the file content, after first fail to upload, the inputstream is not reset when we try to re-upload the file because we still use same request object and not reset the IO stuff, the file content cannot be loaded. Since not all the inputstream implementations support the reset() method, the code is pretty tricky.

Comment: Sounds like you should submit either a pull request to the github repo, or a bug/feature request.